# Laravel: Allowed memory size exhausted when print_r the query output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've read tens of questions reporting this problem and in all of them the best answer was "increase your `memory_limit`". Fair enough, but here I have a `memory_limit=128M` and I'm trying to retrieve **two** lines, so I guess there's an error in the query.

This is the code in `LampsController@create`:

```
$families = DB::table('families AS f')
    ->join('products_families AS pf', 'pf.family_id', '=', 'f.id')
    ->join('products AS p', 'pf.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('f.code'))
    ->where('p.category', '=', 'lamps');
// $families = Collection::unwrap($families);
print_r($families); exit;
```

The database schema is simple:

A) table `families`

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | code | name | created_at | updated_at |
|    |      |      |            |            |
----------------------------------------------
```

B) table `products_families`

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | product_id | family_id | created_at | updated_at |
|    |            |           |            |            |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

C) table `products`

```
-------------------------------------------
| id | category | created_at | updated_at |
|    |          |            |            |
-------------------------------------------
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98570240 bytes)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why `DB::raw('f.code')`? Can you try with just simply `'f.code'`?

Comment: First thing you have not added `get()` to get the result, you can do `dd()` or if you want to print you can use `toSql()`

Comment: @NikolaGavric You're right, I used `DB::raw()` because firstly I had in mind another query

Comment: You've resolved the issue?

Comment: @GaneshGhalame I spent half an hour concentrating on the query and the joins thinking the problem stood there, forgetting completely to add `get()`. Shame on me. Thank you Ganesh

Comment: @Brigo cool it happens

Comment: Stop printing variables and use a debugger! One used to debug code this way 15 years ago.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for having shared your thought. I'll start reading about PHP debuggers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `get()` to get the result of query, If you want to print query you can use `toSql()`